# clone of polymer element remove template of polymer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

my polymer element:

```
<ele-label id="newLabel" color="#000000" bgColor="#f1f1f1"  eleHeight="30" eleWidth="50" text="Name:" eleDisplay="inline-block"  elefloat="left"></ele-label>
```

but when I clone this element inner html will removed.

can any one help me ?

```
<polymer-element name="ele-label" attributes="text color eleid eleWidth eleHeight fontSize bgColor paddingTop paddingBottom paddingLeft paddingRight eleDisplay elefloat" > <template> <div><label style="font-size:{{fontSize}}pt; color:{{color}} ;">{{text}}</label></div> </template></polymer-element>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the inner HTML will be removed?

Comment: template of my polymer component.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/dSJAY/

Comment: you have no text inside that element but saying html will removed.... what's that?

Comment: sorry for explanation of Que but this is my custom element  <polymer-element name="ele-label" attributes="text color eleid eleWidth eleHeight fontSize bgColor paddingTop paddingBottom paddingLeft paddingRight eleDisplay elefloat" >
    
    <template> <div><label style="font-size:{{fontSize}}pt; color:{{color}} ;">{{text}}</label></div>
</template>

Comment: The template is in shadow DOM, not the main DOM.

Comment: my div with label will remove when i clone this custom element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4VTEk/1/

This works, but only with JQuery 2.1.0 or newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally got solution

**polylabel1** : id of my div in side template of polymer element.

```
 Polymer('ele-label', {
 ready: function()
        {
            this.innerHTML=this.$.polylabel1.outerHTML;
        }
 attributeChanged: function()
        {
            this.innerHTML=this.$.polylabel1.outerHTML;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `<template>` tag in Polymer, it creates a [shadow DOM](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html), which is not part of the main DOM. You won't see the elements in the DOM itself, because it's not there. Take a look at the article i linked to learn more.

EDIT: It sounds like jQuery is not cloning the element's shadow with it. Try using `.clone(true)` to also clone related data.

Comment: thanks for ans but custom element is not display after clone.

Comment: What does clone mean here?

Comment: clone means copy of element

Comment: var $label = $('#newLabel').clone()

Comment: Sorry, i don't think i can help further. I'm just learning Polymer myself.