# cloning a polymer element with content insertion points is not working properly

Tags: polymer-1.0

This is the template of my element

```
<template>
<div>
  <content select="div"></content>

  <p>Test Para</p>
  <content select="h5"></content>
</div>
<div>
  <p>last paragrah</p>
</div>
```

And in my index file, I am using the custom element as follows

```
<test-clone id="testClone">
  <h5>Testing clone</h5>
  <h5>Testing clone2</h5>
  <div>Hello World</div>
</test-clone>
```

When I clone the above element, the content insertion is getting messed up and the element is not cloned properly.

Included jsbin examples ( works only in chrome)

http://jsbin.com/zuruqomubo/edit?html,output

​
http://jsbin.com/xiqevugeyi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip to user @nirav-alagiya for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680770/clone-of-polymer-element-remove-template-of-polymer-element#answer-22754268):

**polylabel1** : id of your div inside template of polymer element.

```
Polymer('ele-label', {
 ready: function()
        {
            this.innerHTML=this.$.polylabel1.outerHTML;
        }
 attributeChanged: function()
        {
            this.innerHTML=this.$.polylabel1.outerHTML;
        }
}
```